# Simple map for a text game in python using tables and turtle graphics with a 6*6 table and a 600*600 canvas in turtle

Tags: python

I want to make a map for a simple text game in python, I want to split a 600*600 canvas into 100*100 quadrants that correspond to a coordinate inside of a 2D list.
I want to section off my canvas and associate it's section as coordinates on my 6*6 table, if anyone knows how to do that? Thanks

My code:

```
#dungos + dragos ver 0.1| #
import turtle

def main():
        tina = turtle.Turtle()
        screen = turtle.Screen()
        Map = [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]

        for row in Map:
                for item in row:
                        print(item, end=' ')

                print('\n')
        screen.setup(600,600)
        tina.shape('arrow')
        tina.speed(10)

main()
```

I will be adding to this right now I'm just working on the map for now.

Comment: That's nice. Do you have a question? What is it?

Comment: I want to know how to section off my canvas, and associate it's sections with a placing in my table

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of your 6x6 map on top of your 600x600-pixel canvas. The coordinates
of the 4 map corners are given inside the sections, and the corners of the canvas
itself are labeled.

Your question is, how to identify the canvas coordinates of the 4 corners of
the canvas square that a map square occupies. Each map square occupies a 100x100-pixel square in the canvas. The trick is to figure out the canvas coordinates
for the 4 corners of for an arbitrary map square (i,j).

```
(0,0)                                    (599,0)
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
|(0,0) |      |      |      |      |(5,0)|
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
+------+------*------*------+------+-----+
|      |      |######|      |      |     |
|      |      |######|      |      |     |
+------+------*------*------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|      |      |      |      |      |     |
| (0,5)|      |      |      |      |(5,5)|
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
(0,599)                                 (599,599)
```

Consider a few concrete examples:

```
map square     canvas square (upper left and lower right corners)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
(0,0)          (0,0), (99,99)
(5,5)          (500, 500), (599, 599)
```

It should not be too hard convince yourself that this generalizes to

```
map square     canvas square
---------------------------------------------------
(i,j)          (100*i, 100*j), (100*i+99, 100*j+99)
```

Conversely, an arbitrary point `(x,y)` in the canvas is found in map square `(x//100, y//100)`.

Comment: I'll use this info and try to keep working on this, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Below is code showing how something like that might be done.

Transforming screen coordinate values into table indices is occurs in the `handle_clicks()` function which also prints the final result. It's shown as a series of separate computations to make it easier to understand what's involved—they could have all been combined into a single calculation, but that would have hidden the mathematical reasoning behind it).

```
import turtle

SCREEN_MAP_SIZE = 600
SCREEN_QUAD_SIZE = 100
MAP_SIZE = int(SCREEN_MAP_SIZE/SCREEN_QUAD_SIZE)

def display_map(game_map):
    """ Output contents of game map. """
    for row in game_map:
        for item in row:
            print(item, end=' ')
        print()

def handle_clicks(x, y):
    """ Convert screen mouse clicks to game_map indices. """
    # Convert coordinate values from range:
    #   -(SCREEN_MAP_SIZE/2)...(SCREEN_MAP_SIZE/2) -> 0..SCREEN_MAP_SIZE-1
    x, y = int(x + SCREEN_MAP_SIZE/2), int(y + SCREEN_MAP_SIZE/2)

    # Convert coordinate values from range
    #   0..SCREEN_MAP_SIZE-1 -> 0..MAP_SIZE-1
    x, y = int(x/SCREEN_MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE), int(y/SCREEN_MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE)

    # Invert y coordinate value from range
    #   0..MAP_SIZE-1 -> MAP_SIZE-1..0
    y = MAP_SIZE-1 - y
    print('clicked on game_map ({}, {})'.format(x, y))

def main():
    tina = turtle.Turtle()
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.onclick(handle_clicks)

    game_map = [[0 for _ in range(MAP_SIZE)] for _ in range(MAP_SIZE)]
    display_map(game_map)

    screen.setup(SCREEN_MAP_SIZE, SCREEN_MAP_SIZE)

    tina.shape('arrow')
    tina.speed(10)

    screen.mainloop()

main()
```